# Alignment in Jasper Report

Tags: java, swing, jasper-reports, alignment

Can I pass properties like height,width,top,left of parameter through java code(Swing) for Jasper report

Comment: I am not sure i understand what you mean by passing properties of a parameter

Comment: I am saying can i set the size(height,width,Left,Top) of text field,image etc used in Jasper Report through Java code

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear or specific and i am unaware of what you have tried or searched.
So, not really sure what type of parameters you need to pass through or how you want, but maybe this will help you have a starting point: [JasperFillManager.fillReport](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperFillManager.html#fillReport%28net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport,%20java.util.Map%29). You can pass parameters via a `JasperFillManager.fillReport`.
Also have a look at [exporter parameters](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRExporterParameter.html#JRExporterParameter%28java.lang.String%29) which might help.

Comment: Thanks for answer but I am saying can i set the size(height,width,Left,Top) of text field,image etc used in Jasper Report through Java code

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but have a look at http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRPropertiesMap.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29 and get the properties of a field via jasperReport.getFields() and getting that field. And of course set the properties of that field, if size/position are available, have not worked with that much, so can't say for sure - but do try something.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you want to define the style of an object by means of parameters, but it´s not possible define style like height, width... across the parameters. What you could do is use conditional Style.